# how to handle months value in dateadd

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know what the problem is but can anyone please suggest as how to resolve this query.

The problem is when i calculate for months in dateadd i am getting value more than 98540 :(

```
declare @Basepool int =10000000
declare @transactioncount bigint =1
declare @Monthnum int=1
declare @ContractId int=1

select CASE @Basepool 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A'
            WHEN -1 THEN 'N/A'
            ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by @ContractId) > @Basepool THEN 'IN-OVERAGE'
                    --WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by @ContractId) + (SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)/MonthNum) > U.BasePool THEN DATEADD(MM, 1, GETDATE())
                    ELSE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(MM,CAST(ROUND((@Basepool - SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)) 
                                /(SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)/@Monthnum),0) as INT), GETDATE()),101)

                    --(basepool - sumcontract) / (sumcontract/monthNum ) is the expected months to reach overage
                END 

            END AS  ExpectedDate
```

Comment: It should be 95840 instead of 98540 if the query is executed on 2013-04-29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the maximum months I can add to getdate() is

```
select dateadd(mm, 95840, getdate())
```

What you need is a way to handle the exception case where number of months to be added is greater than the limit.

Try this:

```
select DATEADD(MM
    , case when CAST(ROUND((@Basepool - SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId))/(SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)/@Monthnum),0) as INT)
        > datediff(mm, getdate(), '9999-12-31')
        then datediff(mm, getdate(), '9999-12-31')
        else CAST(ROUND((@Basepool - SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId))/(SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)/@Monthnum),0) as INT)
        end
    , GETDATE())
```

You will need to handle '9999-12-XX' after getting the value back from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your @Basepool variable has very long value which is overflow by INT.
Just try below corrected code.

```
declare @Basepool INT =10000
declare @transactioncount bigint =1
declare @Monthnum int=1
declare @ContractId int=1

select CASE @Basepool 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A'
            WHEN -1 THEN 'N/A'
            ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by @ContractId) > @Basepool THEN 'IN-OVERAGE'
                    ELSE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(MM,CAST(ROUND((@Basepool - SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)) 
                                /(SUM(SUM(@TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by @ContractId)/@Monthnum),0) as INT), GETDATE()),101)
                END 

       END AS  ExpectedDate
```

Comment: i know that that is the problem. I need to have the basepool values as 10000000. The data can't be changed. i have to change the code

Comment: I can add only 95841 maximum month.